# Elastic search wrong response searching 'IN' value

Tags: elasticsearch

Query:

http://:9200/rif_orig/rif/_search?q=F7Y*&from=0&size=10

Response:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "rif_orig",
        "_type": "rif",
        "_id": "INF7YCOriginale",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "IDRIF": "INF7YCOriginale",
          "R01PRO": "IN",
          "R01RIF": "F7YC",
          "R01DES": "CANDELA CHAMPION",
          "R01PRE": "3.20",
          "R01CPR": "",
          "ARTPRO": "IN",
          "ARTPAG": "1",
          "ALTORG": "Originale",
          "timestamp": "201407091018"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Query:

http://:9200/rif_orig/rif/_search?q=IN&from=0&size=10

Response:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried q="IN", q=R01PRO:"IN", q=R01PRO:(IN) q=R01PRO:"\"IN"\" same results....
'IN' is a reserved word? How can I escape it.
I'm using elastich search 0.9 is old but can't upgrade it immediately...
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Elasticsearch are you using? "IN" is a [stop word](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query/), but stop words are not removed by default in Elasticsearch versions that are greater than 1.0. Either you are using an old version of Elasticsearch or the removal of stop words has been enabled.